# String parser in C and C#

Tags: c#, c, parsing

I have a string, `"-(1-cos(R*T))/R"`, that I need to be evaluated in both C and C#. Is there a library, or a quick way to do this? Or do I need to write my own parser?

I'm also assuming that R and T are known and are local variables.

Comment: `if (input == "-(1-cos(R*T))/R") return -(1-cos(R*T))/R;` This?

Comment: No, more like if R = 1 and T = 1, then                               `if (input == "-(1-cos(R*T))/R)" return -0.459697694;`

Comment: Well, if you have exactly the string `"-(1-cos(R*T))/R"` as the input, and you have declared R to be `1` and T to be `1`, you can indeed simply return `-0.459697694`. But I presume that's not what you want. What are you trying to achieve? What parts of the input string are variable? What's the range of expected inputs?

Comment: if want to calculate this string, then use your own string parser method, break your string in char array, but there should be already variables declared with same name as in your string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/FastMathParser.aspx) on CodeProject that's certainly worth a look. There's also a [blog post](http://www.garybeene.com/reviews/rev-parsers.htm) from 2007 that has a list (and benchmarks) of a number, including a half dozen or so that are free.

Answer (score 2):

This is in C#

```
 private void MyMethod1()
        {
            string s = "-(1-cos(R*T))/R";
            float R = 1;
            float T = 1;
            double doutput =-(1-Math.Cos(R*T))/(R);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no `eval()` in `C`.

Answer (score -1):

**Regular Expression** is what you are looking for.

Comment: I doubt it. With regular expressions you can't even check if the number of parentheses is balanced.

Comment: On the other hand, if he's not really trying to parse an arbitrary expression, but a fixed expression with some changing constants, regular expressions might indeed be a good solution.